# How to show a message that a new app version available even if users don't reload the app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, next-pwa

I have a `Next.js` app that uses `next-pwa` library for setting app the service worker. After having deployed a new version I want to show a snackbar that it is available.

Currently, it does show up when I reload the app but it seems pretty useless then because the codebase is already up to date after reloading.

I wonder if it is possible to show that snackbar when a user left the tab open for a while, a new version had been deployed, and then they came back and see the snackbar?

My code currently looks something like this:

```
const useServiceWorker = () => {
  const { showSnackbar } = useSnackbars()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window !== 'undefined' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator && window.workbox !== undefined) {
      const wb = window.workbox

      wb.addEventListener('waiting', () => {
        showSnackbar('A newer version of the app is available!', {
          onClick: () => {
            wb.addEventListener('controlling', () => window.location.reload())
            wb.messageSkipWaiting()
          },
          onClose: () => {
            // do smth else
          },
        })
      })

      wb.register()
    }
  }, [])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder if it is possible to show that snackbar when a user left the tab open for a while, a new version had been deployed, and then they came back and see the snackbar?

You can call `wb.update()` to check for service worker updates. If there is one, it will install it, like `wb.register()` does. You could use `setInterval` to call it at regular intervals.

> Currently, it does show up when I reload the app but it seems pretty useless then because the codebase is already up to date after reloading.

It needs two reloads to fully update. The first runs `wb.register()` again when the component is mounted, which installs the service worker. Once installed, the `'waiting'` event gets triggered, which shows the snackbar. It's not useless at all because you're still running on the old service worker. It takes the combination of `skipWaiting` (to activate the new service worker) and `window.location.reload()` (to update the page) to have a completely up-to-date app.

That said, the first time you deploy the snackbar, your users will need to update the hard way, by closing all clients and reopening the app.